# Cassandra: know when the row got inserted

Tags: cassandra

Small question regarding Cassandra please.

I have a row, I can see it in Cassandra, I can query it etc.
The row looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE student_Registration(
Id int PRIMARY KEY,
Name text,
Event text
);

Id  Name    Event
101 Ashish  Ninza
```

I would like to ask, is there a way to know when this row got inserted please?
I tried looking up for some command to get the insert time, similar to `SELECT TTL (Name)  from`, but for "when the row got inserted" and no luck so far.

May I ask what would be the best way to know when the row got inserted please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the responsibility of the `writetime` function ([doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useWritetime.html)):

```
SELECT writetime(Name) from student_Registration
```

Update: But you need to keep in mind following:

1. the `writetime` shows the update time of the individual cell, and they could be updated separately
2. Write time could be setup explicitly when writing the data

Comment: Learned something new here, indeed working, thanks @Alex

Comment: I initially forgot to add clarification points - just for information